padAngle в графике donut при data = 0 в c3js
Использую c3js. Строю график с входными данными:
 columns: [
     ['data1', 2],
     ['data2', 2],
     ['data3', 2],
     ['data4', 2],
     ['data5', 2],
     ['data6', 3],
     ['data7', 1]
 ]

Добавляю отступы:
 donut: {
     padAngle: 0.05,
 }

Результат: 

Если появляются во входных данных будут значения с 0, то они так же учитываются в отступах и появляется пустота.
columns: [
     ['data1', 0],
     ['data2', 0],
     ['data3', 0],
     ['data4', 2],
     ['data5', 2],
     ['data6', 3],
     ['data7', 1]
 ]


Как этого избежать? При load каждый раз использовать unload для 0 параметров - не подходит
